# How to use $in operator in springboot mongo-data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
 @Query("{ 'name' : { $regex: ?0 }, 'email' : { $regex: ?1}, 'subjects' : { $all: ?2 } , 'institutionId' : ?3 } ")
Page<Teacher> searchTeacher(String name, String email, Set<String> subjects, long institutionId, Pageable pageable);
```

All doesn't work when empty String is passed. Is it just possible to use 'subjects': {$in: ?2}

Where the third argument must contain a regex pattern like [/^/]

Comment: Can you post please sample data? `$all` means your subjects array must have all subjects present... If you change it to `$in` operator, it means any subject is present

Comment: Understood but I need a wild card search for array. Here is the sample data you have asked for. 

{
    "_id" : NumberLong(23),
    "applicationUserId" : NumberLong(68),
    "subjects" : [ 
        "Maths", 
        "English", 
        "Moral Science"
    ],
    "grades" : [ 
        "1", 
        "3", 
        "4"
    ],
    "grade" : "10 B",
    "email" : "mrycavnua@grr.com",
    "institutionId" : NumberLong(56),
    "name" : "Madhan",
    "lastModified" : "4/22/20, 7:34 AM",
    "_class" : "com.institution.model.Teacher"
}

Comment: ```db.getCollection('teachers').find({'name': 'Madhan', 'subjects': {$in: [ /^Maths/]}})```

The above query works fine in fetching the result. Is it possible to have similar behaviour in spring Mongo data ?